# Regex for floating points, range and zero

Tags: swift, regex

I need regex that matches zero, integer and floating point numer in live input but also with length after decimal separator.
So it should be ok when user tap

1. 0, 0,2, 1,1234
2. also it should be valid if typing 0 then 0, then 0,1 etc...
3. also if user tap "." and decimalSeparator is "," validation should fail.
   The problem is that my regex does not match zero:

````
let decimalSeparator = NumberFormatter().decimalSeparator ?? ","
let range = 4
var pattern: String {
 return "^(?![0.]+$)[0-9]{0,10}(?:\\\(decimalSeparator)[0-9]{0,\(range)})?$" 
}
let exp = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern,  options: .caseInsensitive).firstMatch(in: string,
                                                                                   options: [],
                                                                                   range: NSRange(location: 0,
                                                                                                  length: string.count))```
````

Comment: can thousands we typed with commas or spaces? for example  `1 000` or `1,000` ?

Comment: Then remove `(?![0.]+$)` if you want to allow `0`. Why did you use the lookahead? What is the exact requirement? Maybe you need `(?!0+[1-9])`? No one or more zeros before a non-zero char. Or `(?!0+[1-9]|0{2,}\.)`. See https://regex101.com/r/2jeGmv/1

Comment: @Kendle no, without thousands separators. Also In my country we use commas instead dot for floating points.

Comment: Why not just `^[0-9](,[0-9]{0,4})?$` (with separator & range to update with your variables)? See https://regex101.com/r/IPnyxo/1

Comment: @Larme because it does not allow me to delete last digit in field

Comment: Sorry, could you please precise what works for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew removed (?![0.]+$)

Comment: @Kendle and what about the range?

Comment: @Gorthez `string.count` is wrong. You should pass `string.utf16.count` for `NSRange` length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?![0.]+$)` negative lookahead matches a location that is not immediately followed with one or more `.` or zeros till the end of string.

Thus, to allow matching zeros, you need to get rid of the lookahead:

```swift
let decimalSeparator = NumberFormatter().decimalSeparator ?? ","
let range = 4
var pattern: String {
 return "^[0-9]{0,10}(?:\\\(decimalSeparator)[0-9]{0,\(range)})?$" 
}
let exp = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern,  options: .caseInsensitive).firstMatch(in: string,
                                                                                   options: [],
                                                                                   range: NSRange(location: 0,
                                                                                                  length: string.utf16.count))
```